I have been imposed a fine that is higher than my monthly income
I have been imposed a fine that exceeds my monthly income and I am on a fixed income that I can barely afford to live as it is and I have no extra income to pay an extreme amount of money but they do offer a payment plan but they charge fees that would triple the amount of the original amount how do I contest this if the judge is not being fair

You need to consult a lawyer. This site is not a substitute for that.

This depends, of course, on where you are.
In germany, fines for crimes are set as a number of day-equivalents (Tagessätze) and an amount per day-equivalent. The number depends on the severity of the offense and the amount depends on the income of the defendant.
Failure to pay normally results in imprisonment for the indicated number of days, but there may be an option to transform it into community work instead. If the defendant believes that the amount was incorrect, it is also possible to appeal only that part of the decision.
Fines for misdemeanors tend to be lower, and fixed amounts.
Then there are civil judgements, which are debts and not fines. The party being owed a debt may have to go to court if the debt is disputed, and if the debtor does not pay even after the verdicts, the party being owed the debt may involve a court bailiff (Gerichtsvollzieher), first to deliver papers and then to seize assets of the debtor, if there are any.
During all this interest and fees will add to the original debt, and if the debtor pays nothing or not enough, the debt will actually rise rather than fall. It may be reasonable for the debtor to file for bankruptcy.

Just curious, but why did you choose to include the two German words you included in your answer?  When i use Google translate they translate into English just as you wrote in the answer, so i don't see what they add...

@MichaelHall, there are words which have an obvious translation, and some which do not. Without further context, google translate does not get "day equivalent" right, it does get "court bailiff" (to my surprise, I expected it to stumble on both).

It translated "Tagessätze" into "daily rate" for me, which mostly fits in that context.  And I understand that some words don't have a direct corresponding literal translation, but I just question how useful the practice is if you can paraphrase the intent in English.  I'm not picking on you, others do it as well and whenever I translate it I get something pretty much in line with the English answer so I question what value this really adds for the bilingual reader.
